# SQL Server : Tracking a slow running query on completion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Am trying to work on script for slow-running queries. I understand that we can get the list of slow running queries using `sys.dm_exec_requests`. Say, I have a query Q1 which is running very slow, say, 1 hour. Till Q1 is running i.e. executing, I can track it using `sys.dm_exec_requests` DMV. If I understood it right, once Q1 is completed, its statistics will be no more available in this DMV. Instead, we need to look at `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`. But how do I get the statistics of that specific query Q1 which had been slow-running ? Meaning how do I relate the data I earlier got in sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_query_stats?

Comment: for the exact statement you'd relate the two based on the `sql_handle` (assuming you've captured that). for similar queries, you'd related the two based on the `query_hash`.

Comment: @swasheck thanks! I think this works! +1

Comment: If you can add this as an answer, I can mark it right @swasheck !

Answer (score 4):

A quick-and-dirty way to get this information is to run something like this query *while the query you wish to observe is still running*.

```
select 
    st.text,
    r.wait_type,
    r.wait_time,
    r.wait_resource,
    qs.creation_time,
    qs.*
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs 
join sys.dm_exec_requests r
    on r.sql_handle = qs.sql_handle
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) st
```

Note: this will only capture queries that are running at that moment. Additionally, the query stats DMV does not persist across reboots and may also be flushed when under pressure. Joining on `sql_handle` gets you query stats for that exact statement. You can find query stats for "similar" queries (similar logic with difference occurring only in literal values) by joining on `query_hash`.

Answer (score 2):

What I've been using is [Adam Machanic's Who_IS_ACTIVE](http://whoisactive.com) to track the stats for slow running queries. The prod uses the DMV's and will track the stats as mentioned.

One of the great things about sp_whoisactive is that it’s very quick to generate a table to collect the data you need, then run the procedure in a loop with a wait statement to regularly collect the data you want over an interval.

Please read [How to Log Activity Using sp_whoisactive in a Loop](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/log-sp_whoisactive-to-a-table/)

Also, read [here](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/) on how to use it to find stats on slow running queries.

Apart from DMV's, you can use SQL profiler or Extended events to find the stats on slow running queries and troubleshoot the same as explained in [Identifying slow running queries](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/how-to-identify-slow-running-queries-with-sql-profiler/)